# PHP Image manipulation with rotation and crop

Tags: php, image, rotation, crop

I have a problem with image manipulation in php. As they say, a picture paints a thousand words so below is an image to assist me in explaining my situation.

[image: Step 1]

I have a canvas (the picture of a car) and a container (the red rectangle) and the image above is my initial setup. Here are the details that I know about my initial setup:

1. Dimension of the canvas (width & height)
2. Dimension of the container (width & height)
3. Position of the container relative to the top left of the canvas (x, y)

Next I apply a rotation on the canvas at a certain angle counter-clockwise. Assuming the centre of the rotation is the centre of the canvas itself.

[image: Step 2]

As of this step, I know 2 additional details:

1. The angle of the rotation
2. The direction of the rotation (counter-clockwise)

Things to take note of:

1. The container itself didn't rotate, just the canvas.
2. The dimension of the canvas may have changed. In this case, both the width and height of the canvas have increased.

Details that I DO NOT know anymore AFTER the rotation:

1. Dimension of the canvas
2. Position of the container relative to the top left of the canvas

Then, the container is used to crop the canvas at its current position. The image below is the result I'm trying to achieve using php.

[image: Step 3]

I have never done any image manipulation in php before. Code examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: nothing to do with php. it's just basic trigonometry, and the same "math" would apply in pretty much any language you choose to do this in.

Comment: This is not "write me a code" website

Comment: @fsw, I didn't say that "codes examples" is a must. At least some explanation to point me in the correct direction. Code examples just help me understand better ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here

[Crop and rotate images with JS and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791763/crop-and-rotate-images-with-js-and-php)

I didn't know that we have to manually get the dimension of the canvas after the rotation and recalculate the relative position of the container based on the new canvas dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Croxall wrote a really good overview of image manipulation with PHP on Smashing Magazine:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/05/image-manipulation-with-jquery-and-php-gd/

But I wouldn't bother reinventing the wheel here - Cloudinary pretty much did all the work for you. They even have a free 500MB plan you can use to test it out and compare results. Here's an overview of their image manipulation capabilities:
http://cloudinary.com/features#image_manipulation

Good luck !
Ohad